# Laravel Many to Many Sync with additional column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-relations

Laravel version 7.0

I have `Team` model and `User` model, `team_has_users` table.

`team_has_users` table has `team_id`, `user_id`, `role` columns.

One user can belong to one team with different roles.

For instance, one user can belong to one team as a client and as an employee.

in `Team` model, I set a relation like this.

```
public function users(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'team_has_user', 'team_id', 'user_id')
       ->withPivot('role');
}
```

When I attach users to the team, it worked well like this.

```
    $item->users()->attach($request->clients, ['role'=>'client']);
    $item->users()->attach($request->employees, ['role'=>'employee']);
```

But, when I was going to sync them, I couldn't do.

I tried to search and found a similar one `syncwithoutDetaching` but it seems not to fit for my case.
`team_has_users` table can be like this.

```
team_id    user_id    role
1           1         client
1           1         employee
1           2         client
1           1         other
...
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While **attach** you can pass an additional array as you have passed.

```
$item->users()->attach($request->clients, ['role'=>'client']);
$item->users()->attach($request->employees, ['role'=>'employee']);
```

But In the sync you have to pass pivot value inside the array, I have mention example below.

```
$item->roles()->sync([1 => ['role' => 'client'], 2 => ['role' => 'employee']);
```

Check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) sync part,

Comment: Thanks, can't I do `$item->users()->sync($request->clients, ['role'=>'client']` ?

Comment: Should I divide the array separately?

Comment: No you can't. In syncing you've to assign value of pivot. and therefore you have make array. `[$clientid=>['role'=>'client'],[$employeeid=>['role'=>'employee']]`

Comment: This didn't work if `$request->clients` and `$request->employees` have some same ids.

Comment: This didn't work because of `team_id` and `user_id` are same for `client` and `employee`. Otherwise as per your question this is the right solution. You have design wrong database. already user + role has relation ship and in your case you have made wrong DB design.

Comment: Then should I make the another table `user_role`? and need to put that table's row_id ?

Comment: The user belongs to Team right? and user should have multiple role. as per DB design you should have three table. team, user, role..team hasMany user.. user belongsToMany role.