# Laravel | PHP Array Recursive Merge with preserving key

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I have three arrays.

```
$data1 = []; $data2 =[]; $data3 = [];

foreach($request->clients as $client)
{
  $data1[]= [$client=>['role'=>'client']];
}

foreach($request->employees as $employee)
{
   $data2[]= [$employee=>['role'=>'employee']];
}

foreach($request->users as $user)
{
   $data3[] = [$user=>['role'=>'user']];
}

$data1 = [1=>['role'=>'client'], 2=>['role'=>'client']];
$data2 = [1=>['role'=>'employee']];
$data3 = [1=>['role'=>'user']];

//merge or recursive merge or... $data1, $data2, $data3.

$result = [1=>['role'=>'client'], 2=>['role'=>'user'], 1=>['role'=>'user'], 1=>['role'=>'employee']];
```

How can I get result like above?
This is for [Laravel Many to Many Sync with additional column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008368/laravel-many-to-many-sync-with-additional-column/63008422#63008422).

Thanks

Comment: well, so we can't do that??

Comment: well, not the same row with multi role. I am going to save like this `1-1-client`, `1-1-employee`, `1-1-user`, `2-1-user`..

Comment: You are right. hmm, then first of all, I need to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008368/laravel-many-to-many-sync-with-additional-column/63008422#63008422

Comment: ie)  memberships table that relates users to teams, a roles table for Role, and a membership_role table for Role to Membership.

Comment: I have made a sample answer that should work for you.

Comment: Are users, clients and employees all User models? Or are they all separate models?

Comment: They are all User models.

Comment: Ok good. Did my solution below work for you?

Comment: checking now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After discussion with OP, the structure, needed to be changed to allow for the relationships role to be able to associate with many roles. To achieve this, we can do as follows.

Schema:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
});

Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
});

Schema::create('memberships', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('team_id');
    // Any other data you want here is fine
});

Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
});

Schema::create('membership_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('membership_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
});
```

Now for Membership.php

```
class Membership extends Model
{
    public static function create(User $user, Team $team, array $roles = [])
    {
        $membership = new self();
        $membership->user_id = $user->id;
        $membership->team_id = $team->id;
        $membership->save();


        $attach = [];

        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            $attach[] = Role::resolveId($role);
        }

        $membership->roles()->attach($attach);

        return $membership;
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function syncRoles(array $roles)
    {
        $sync = [];

        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            $sync[] = Role::resolveId($role);
        }

        $this->roles()->sync($sync);
    }
}
```

And Role.php

```
class Role extends Model
{
    const CLIENT = 'client';
    const EMPLOYEE = 'employee';
    const USER = 'user';

    public function memberships()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Membership::class);
    }

    public static function resolveId()
    {
        if (is_int($role)) {
            return $role;
        }

        if (is_string($role)) {
            $role = Role::where('name', $role)->first();
        }


        return $role->id;
    }
}
```

Now you can assume the other classes are implemented with the obvious relations and do:

```
foreach($request->clients as $client)
{
    if (!isset($roleSync[$client])) {
        $roleSync[$client] = [];
    }

    $roleSync[$client][] = Role::CLIENT;
}

foreach($request->employees as $employee)
{
    if (!isset($roleSync[$employee])) {
        $roleSync[$employee] = [];
    }

    $roleSync[$employee][] = Role::EMPLOYEE;
}

foreach($request->users as $user)
{
    if (!isset($roleSync[$user])) {
        $roleSync[$user] = [];
    }

    $roleSync[$user][] = Role::USER;
}

$ids = array_keys($roleSync);
$users = User::with('membership.roles')
               ->whereIn('id', $ids)
               ->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $roles = $roleSync[$user->id];
    $user->membership->syncRoles($roles)
}
```