# Laravel: how to store same relation but with different additional column

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table

tables that I have:

```
users: id, name.
roles: id, name.
role_user: user_id, role_id, company_id.
```

the main idea is that user can have same roles but in different companies.
for example:

```
user_id | role_id | company_id
______________________________
      1 |       1 |         1
      1 |       1 |         2
```

when I try `sync()`, it stores only one row instead of two, because of `user_id` and `role_id` in both cases are same.
couldn't find solution, maybe it's my bad that I couldn't provide correct sentence to search :)

Comment: Post the table definition. It seems you have a unique constraint on user_id + role_id.

Comment: you can use attach() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your main problem is when you try to `sync()` for other company it's remove the other one

you can try this

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
// sync a specific company_id 
$user->roles()->sync([$role_id => ['company_id' => $company_id]]);
```

the `sync()` method by default syncing the 2 main keys in your situation is `user_id` & `role_id` , But if you need to sync more than that you need to add it as a parameter in brackets

here same example for your case :
[sync paivot columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008368/laravel-many-to-many-sync-with-additional-column)